# Arbitrary shaped Feedforward Neural Network in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am making a script that has some generative aspect to it, and I need to generate **arbitrary shaped  feedforward NNs**. The idea is to pass a list With the number of number of neurons in each layer, and the number of layers is determined by the length of the list:

```
shape = [784,64,64,64,10]
```

I tried something like this:
shapenn = [784,64,64,64,10]

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shapenn):
        super().__init__()
        self.shapenn = shapenn
        self.fcl = [] # list with fully conected leyers 
        for i in range(len(act_funs)):
            self.fcl.append(nn.Linear(self.nnarch[i],self.nnarch[i+1]))
net = Net(shapenn)
```

While the fully connected layers are created correctly in the list `fcl`, `net` is not initialized properly for example it has not `net.parameters()`.
I am sure there is a correct way to do this, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) in place of the built-in python list (similarly use [`nn.ModuleDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleDict.html#torch.nn.ModuleDict) in place of python dictionaries). These behave like a normal list except that they must only contain instances that subclasses `nn.Module` and using them signals that the modules contained in the list should be considered submodules of your module. For example

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fcl = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(5):
            self.fcl.append(nn.Linear(10, 10))

net = Net()
print([name for name, val in net.named_parameters()])
```

prints

```
['fcl.0.weight', 'fcl.0.bias', 'fcl.1.weight', 'fcl.1.bias', 'fcl.2.weight', 'fcl.2.bias', 'fcl.3.weight', 'fcl.3.bias', 'fcl.4.weight', 'fcl.4.bias']
```